# How to format CSS for 8.5x11 inch printed pages

Tags: css, templates, printing

I am looking for help setting up the initial DIV that will fit within the borders of the letter paper.  I'll loop for dynamic page content ending each page with `page-break-after; always;.

I've been using the trial and error approach and have now run out of paper to trial with.

How do you setup the div container where positions relate to the paper margins?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, *what's the **question** here*?

Comment: Edited to define question more clearly.

Comment: "run out of paper" - you do know there's a print preview option, right?

Comment: Yes.  The print preview isn't accurate enough.  I'm trying to print a unique serial number in a box on pre-printed forms.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After using a CSS reset template, and with "shrink to page" turned off in print options I am able to make a DIV that is 7" (about 670px) wide and 9.5 (about 900px) high.  I can position inside this box.

It translates fine between the printers I have connected.  If my calculations are correct, the print DPI is about 95ppi.

```
#printPage
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 670px; /* width: 7in; */
  height: 900px; /* or height: 9.5in; */
  clear: both;
  background-color: gray;
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

Then positioning like this works:

```
#cube
{ 
  position: relative;
  top: 1in;
  left: 1in;
  width: 1in;
  height: 1in;
  background-color: white;
}
```